# Retrofit: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, retrofit2

NullPointerException and No adapter attached; skipping layout occurs everytime I test this app on the gennymotion.i have read other questions related to same problem but none help.

**logcat**

09-20 13:21:13.738 4658-4658/com.example.kiran.detailapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.kiran.detailapp, PID: 4658
                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.example.kiran.detailapp.RecyclerAdapter.getItemCount(RecyclerAdapter.java:38)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3493)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3019)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:697)
                                                                               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

**Contact.java**

```
package com.example.kiran.detailapp;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class Contact {
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String Name;

    @SerializedName("email")
    private String Email;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }
}
```

**ApiClient.java**

```
    package com.example.kiran.detailapp;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class ApiClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://10.0.3.2/ContactApp/";

    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getApiClient()
    {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**ApiInterface.java**

```
    package com.example.kiran.detailapp;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
public interface ApiInterface {


    @POST("ReadContacts.php")
    Call<List<Contact>> getContacts();
}
```

**RecyclerAdapter.java**

```
    package com.example.kiran.detailapp;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Contact> contacts;
    public RecyclerAdapter(List<Contact> contacts)
    {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.Name.setText(contacts.get(position).getName());
        holder.Email.setText(contacts.get(position).getEmail());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contacts.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView Name,Email;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            Email = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.email);

        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.example.kiran.detailapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerAdapter adapter;
    private List<Contact> contacts;
    private ApiInterface apiInterface;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(contacts);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.Recycleview);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<List<Contact>> call = apiInterface.getContacts();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Contact>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Contact>> call, Response<List<Contact>> response) {
                contacts = response.body();

                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Contact>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: No adapter attached; skipping layout occurs everytime

Comment: Initialize contatcs. `private List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some issues in the code.

1) your `contacts`var is going un initialized inside the adapter.

2) You have set recyclerview inside `onResponse` method which is running in background thread.

**Solution:**

You need to initialize contacts and then give them values in `onResponse` method and set adapter on `activity's` `runOnUiThread` method.

Hope this code will help.

1) initialise contacts

```
private List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
```

2) give expected values in `onResponse` method and initialize adapter there and remove initialization form `onCreate` method.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Contact>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Contact>> call, Response<List<Contact>> response) {
            contacts = response.body();
            adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(contacts);
            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Contact>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
```

Comment: No adapter attached; skipping layout occurs everytime

Comment: ok. so If the crash issue solved by the answer please accept it as answer and for the layout skipping, refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to initialize the arraylist

```
 private List<Contact> contacts;
```

then in `onCreate()` do this

```
contacts= new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: No adapter attached; skipping layout occurs everytime